# Inserting variable into MySQL datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, insert

I am getting the date and time from user input and then trying to insert the given date and time into a datetime column in MySQL. This it doesn't seem to be working. However, when I insert `NOW()` it works fine.

I have the variables: `$year`, `$month`, `$date`, `$hour`, and `$minute`.

And this is what I am doing:

```
    $i_date = "$year";
    $month= sprintf("%02s", $month); // These add a leading zero to numbers less than 10
    $i_date .= "$month";
    $date = sprintf("%02s", $date);
    $i_date .= "$date";
    $hour = sprintf("%02s", $hour);
    $i_date .= "$hour";
    $minute = sprintf("%02s", $minute);
    $i_date .= "$minute";
    $i_date .= "00"; // These are for seconds.
```

This gives the me the correct format for the date. I have checked it by echoing it out and then trying to manually insert into the database and it works.

But when I try to insert `$i_date` into the datetime column via PHP, it does not accept it.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Could you show the exact way you are trying to insert this into your database? Maybe try adding some `:` and `.` or something like that here and there?

Comment: show us the insert into table code..

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to SQL escape values...

Comment: Thanks everyone, but a reply below has fixed the issue. It was just an issue due to formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the hyphens and the colons. Format should be:

```
Y-m-d H:i:s // PHP format
```

For example, the date time right now:

```
2013-06-03 21:09:00
```

And thus, with your code:

```
$i_date = sprintf('%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:00', $year, $month, $date, $hour, $minute);
```

Comment: This worked. I think it was just that my formatting was not correct. Even though, the format I mentioned above worked when I inserted it manually.

Nonetheless, thank you so much. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify all of those repeated sprintfs:

```
$mysql_date = sprintf('%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d', $year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for the date is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS`, so you assuming `$year` is guaranteed to be four digits, you should update it to

```
 $i_date = "$year-$month-$date $hour:$minute:00";
```

after all of the 0 padding is done.